# Company Device Management on Separate User?

Tags: macbook-pro, security, mdm

I am doing an event with a company that wants to give me a corporate email. They want to set it up using a device management profile on my personal mac. 
Is there a way to protect and keep my personal files/data/"personal email" separate without using a 2nd laptop?

Would creating a separate user account on my laptop silo the two enough that my personal files are not at risk of being read or wiped?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't because it would be a massive security hole.

It's called mobile *device* management, not mobile *user* management and this is for a reason - how secure would it be if all the user had to do to bypass corporate security policies was create a new user?

If you want to keep your personal data on your personal Mac secure from corporate entities and their MDM software, use a different Mac.  It's probably very feasible that the company can provide you a loaner Mac for this event.